# MATLAB cell assignment with logical mask

Tags: matlab, image-processing

my problem is as follows:

**input**

a.  a cell of size [m,n,k] with strings.

```
in = cell(2,2,2);
in{1,1,1} = 'a'; in{2,1,1} = 'a'; in{1,2,1} = 'a'; in{2,2,1} = 'a';   
in{1,1,2} = 'a'; in{2,1,2} = 'a'; in{1,2,2} = 'a'; in{2,2,2} = 'a';
```

b. a logical mask of size [m,n,k].

```
mask = true(2,2,2); mask(1,1,2) = false; mask (2,1,1) = false;
mask(1,1,1) = false; mask(1,2,1) = false;
```

c. an additional string

```
str = 'b'
```

**desired Output**

a cell of size [m,n,k], s.t for each coordinate i,j,t.

if mask(i,j,t)==true -> out(i,j,t) = in(i,j,t) concatenated with the additional strings.

otherwise -> out(i,j,t) = in(i,j,t)

In the example above, out should be:

```
out(:,:,1) = 
'a'    'a' 
'a'    'ab'
out(:,:,2) = 
'a'     'ab'
'ab'    'ab'
```

What is the most elegant way to do it with MATLAB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use logical indexing and the function `strcat`

```
out = in;
out(mask) = strcat(out(mask),'b')
```